# How to highlight output from diff command and make them side by side?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, text-processing, diff

I have two files

```
$ cat file1.txt
UUXX:1
UUXX:2

$ cat file2.txt
UUXX:3
UUXX:1
```

I want to use this command

```
$ diff --old-group-format=$'\e[0;31m%<\e[0m' --new-group-format=$'\e[0;31m%>\e[0m' --unchanged-group-format=$'\e[0;32m%=\e[0m' file1.txt file2.txt
```

I got this output with `UUXX:3` and `UUXX:2` in red and `UUXX:1` in green

```
UUXX:3
UUXX:1
UUXX:2
```

But I want to make them side by side like this, and keep the `UUXX:3` and `UUXX:2` in red and both `UUXX:1` in green.

```
UUXX:1                             UUXX:3
UUXX:2                             UUXX:1
```

Comment: `sdiff` any help here?

Comment: sdiff didn't work the way i want

Comment: If you are familiar with `vim`, `vimdiff` is a good choice

Comment: have you tried `-y`, `diff -y file1.txt file2.txt | colordiff`

Comment: What version of `diff` do you have?

Comment: @sys463 my diff version is 2.8.1

Comment: @Thor I want to use that in a shell script.

Comment: @SivaPrasath I don’t have colordiff and I can’t install it, this is out of my control.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly the thing required, but it's similar:

```
diff  --color=always -y file1 file2
```

Outputs in red, green, and white:

```
                                  > UUXX:3
UUXX:1                              UUXX:1
UUXX:2                            <
```